# How to restore XML with DOMDocument

Tags: xml, domdocument

Good afternoon. There is a document emall.by/deal.xml It mistake. The client does not want to edit it, and a simple mistake. The problem in the sign &. Those. elementary description should be put in the CDATA

```html
$reader->open("text.xml");
$item = array();
while ($reader->read()) {
    switch ($reader->nodeType) {
        case (XMLReader::ELEMENT):
            if ($reader->localName == 'currency') {
                $item = $reader->expand();
                $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->recover = TRUE;
                $node = $dom->importNode($item,true);
                $dom->appendChild($node);
                // загружаем в simpleXML только текущий node
                $xml = simplexml_import_dom($node);
                $id = $xml->attributes()->id;

            }
    }
}
```

How to restore the line or get them to read?

Comment: You are in an international forum please write in english

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Stack Overflow is an English site. Could you please translate your question?

Comment: Use http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ for russian language

Comment: Sorry.Good afternoon. There is a document http://emall.by/deal.xml

It mistake. The client does not want to edit it, and a simple mistake. The problem in the sign &. Those. elementary description should be put in the CDATA

How to restore the line or get them to read?

Comment: Please edit the question: do not amend with comments.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CDATA does not help and any XML APIs do not help either as the entity reference `&deg;` would need a declaration. So someone needs to edit the file and either declare the entity or you can use the character `°` literally or with a numeric character reference in the form `&#176;`.